# PHP: Work with a large string with quotes

Tags: php, escaping, quotes

Suppose I have a large string of HTML code. It has both double quotes and single quotes. How can I work with such a string? I want to assign it to a `php var` but there's a quote clash whether I use double quotes or single quotes. Is there any way to assign this string to a var without having to manually add slashes to all the quotes?

It could be something like this:

```
<div class="name">Sally O'Connel</div>
```

Only the string is longer so there will be multiple occurances of single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: Have you researched heredoc or nowdoc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [HEREDOC/NOWDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$var = <<<HTML
<div class="name">Sally O'Connel</div>
HTML;
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed. Marking as answer ETA 6 mins

Answer (score 1):

```
 $var = file_get_contents('file.with.your.long.and.windy.html');
```

would be apparently the only sane way. PHP files are for the code.

Answer (score 0):

use Heredoc

```
$var = <<<HTML
<div class="name">Sally O'Connel</div>
HTML;
```

Please ensure that there is no space character after `HTML;`